# smb.conf using different SMB protocol for different SMB share

Tags: networking, configuration, samba, smb

So far I was trying to boot the HyperV VM from SMB share, it was failing with error "Remote SMB does not support resiliency". Finally I found that it only works with SMB2_02 protocol by adding below in smb.conf,

```
max protocol = SMB2_02
```

So now I want to create an SMB share for this particular Hyper-V server with SMB2_02 and I don't want to affect other SMB configuration for other shares.

Will it be possible and how?

Comment: Another option may be to add an IP alias and tie two separate samba instances to separate IPs.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller can you give me more details on this please

Comment: I don't have a way to test it, I'm just putting a possibility out there -- you'd (try to) configure each samba instance to listen only on its separate IP address; with separate config files, you could set the "max protocol" separately (in their Global sections)

Comment: @Jeff Schaller it sounds cool to me, let me try this and I will update on this thread Thanks, I was in big trouble and now I see some hope on it :)

Answer (score 1):

Not according to the [documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html). `max protocol` is an alias for `server max protocol`, and that is defined as:

> server max protocol (G)

... where the (G) means:

> The letter G in parentheses indicates that a parameter is specific to the [global] section.